# Error in Querying BIM 360 project attribute

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm currently using an AWS lambda function to automate the creation of a BIM 360 project by using multiple BIM 360 API endpoints.

It's been working fine, but I've just noticed that it stopped working, failing to access `GET projects/:project_id` endpoint. My code accesses each BIM 360 project's `job_number` attribute to filter duplicated projects by using `job_number`. And the code is failing at getting the response of the `GET projects/:project_id` request.

Has there been any change in the API recently? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate the problem is about  it failed when GET projects/:project_id, or it did not return the data that was available before?  We had one issue with GET:Project/users recently, but not GET projects/:project_id. I also tested explictly, it works with my BIM account, no matter US or EMEA account

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thanks so much for the response. It just failed to get the response sometimes when I can the `GET projects/:project_id` endpoint. Here's what I found: The API request works well when there's at least a few minutes of gap between multiple requests. When multiple requests are sent to Forge almost at the same time, it seems to fail to get the response. Is it what Forge API supposed to be? Can it not handle mulitple requests at the same time?

Comment: I tried to put an answer. If it helps your case, please set it as solution :) If not, please feel free to update further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the latest reply, it looks you hit rate limit. If am correct,  the response error code is 429.  Each category API has restriction of rate limit. e.g. This is rate limit of Data Management API
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/dm-rate-limits/
And this is BIM360 API:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/rate-limits/

So, you will need to set some delays of each call to meet the rate, or use some async management methods such as async-pool in Node.js to control the calls rate or every minute.

Comment: This is really helpful for me to understand the rate limit. Thanks so much @XiaodongLiang